# IN clause in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the below dataset

```
data a;
input id stat$;
datalines;
10 a
20 a
10 t
40 t
;
run;
```

I am writing the below macro

```
%macro ath(inp);
data _null_;
set a (where=(id=&inp);
----if any one of the status of ID is 'a' then put 'valid';
else put 'invalid';----
%mend;
```

I am a beginner in SAS. Please help me in writing the syntax for - if any one of the status of ID is 'a' then put 'valid'; else put 'invalid'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to scan over all (selected) rows in the input data, and test whether any of them has `ID = 'a'`. You don't do this with an `IN` clause; that's for testing against a set of values for each row, as opposed to testing against one value for all rows.

```
data _null_;
    set a (where=(id = &inp);
    if id = 'a' then do;
        put 'valid';
        stop;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a `where` statement here, surely all the id's you select are going to be valid? I.e. you are selecting all the rows where `id = &inp`, so if your variable `&inp = 'a'` then all rows of the new dataset will be valid. Sorry if I have missed something here!